# worklight 5.06 error - Error creating bean with name 'deployService'

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

After doing a manual install we are receiving the following issue when connecting to oracle on a worklight 5.06 install on tomcat7 on linux (RHEL 5.9):

```
SEVERE: com.worklight.server.bundle.project.messages:logger.projectStartFailed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'deployService' defined in URL [jar:file:/usr/share/java/tomcat7/worklight-jee-library.jar!/conf/integration.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
```

Looking at previous postings I did see this asked before - with the following in an answer:

> if the database is on a different machine than the tomcat (make sure you have set the right >remote access permissions for MySQL (for testing only: try giving Worklight DB user an >untrusted access .i.e. use "@%" ))

I have validated the permissions/connection is working as expected (created a test jsp page to do a select * from dual;

> another issue: if you are installing Worklight on Tomcat: did you run the SQL schema script >to create the Worklight schema ? you must run it manually (there is a workaround though: >connect to the same database from Eclipse which runs a Worklight project)

I did run the create-worklight-oracle.sql script and can see the associated tables have been created here.

> what files do you have under /var/lib/tomcat6/worklight.home/td_ibm/data/export/adapters ? >If its empty, there maybe a bug in the Worklight code.

I don't see any type of data structure like this - guessing this is from a previous version?

Thanks,
-Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dan,

This error might happen when Worklight fails to create its '*worklight.home*' directory structure, which I think is created under the '*<tomcat7>/bin*' directory.

One possible reason is that the user credential given to the '*tomcat*' process does not have writing permissions to the '*<tomcat7>/bin*' directory - I have seen this happening when installing Worklight onto a Tomcat from '*yum install tomcat7*' (a JPackage module).

If that assumption is correct, I would suggest you to try one of these two options:

1. Allow the user executing the '*tomcat*' process to write to the '*<tomcat7>*' directory and all subdirectories
2. Manually create the directory '*<tomcat7>/bin/worklight.home*' and make sure that the user executing the '*tomcat*' process can write to it

Upon restarting Tomcat Worklight should be able to create the '*worklight.home*' structure needed to complete the initialization process. If you have Tomcat installed by '*yum*', please pay attention to the symlinks and make sure that the '*tomcat*' process can write to them.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks eabe - this was the issue - once tomcat was able to create the directory everything came up properly. This was an issue with how the tomcat7 package is installed from yum from the RHEL AWS2.0 repositories.